# Specify host and port in mlflow.yml and run "kedro mlflow ui", but host and port still default (localhost:5000) not change

Tags: mlflow, kedro

I build sample kedro project refer to [this page](https://kedro-mlflow.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.0/source/03_getting_started/01_example_project.html),
and specify host as my global ip address in mlflow.yml.
but when I hit "kedro mlflow ui" command, it still listen to local.
even I only specify port to 5001 (not default) in mlflow.yml, it does not work.
Can anyone help me.

python version: 3.6.8 (anaconda)
kedro version: 0.17.0
kedro mlflow version: 0.6.0

Answer (score 5):

*(Disclaimer: I am the author of kedro-mlflow)*

Hi,

you are not doing anything wrong, it appears to be a bug (thanks for reporting it!): the `kedro mlflow ui` command does not retrieve the `ui` and `port` parameters from the configuration, as we can see [in the source code](https://github.com/Galileo-Galilei/kedro-mlflow/blob/477147f6aa2dbf59c67f916b2002dea2de74d1fd/kedro_mlflow/framework/cli/cli.py#L149-L151) (this regression probably fell of the cracks during a refactoring).

**Short term solution**: Use directly the `mlflow ui` function as [described in mlflow documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-ui) , e.g.:

```
mlflow ui --mlflow-tracking-uri <your-tracking-uri> --port <your-port> --host <your-host>
```

Keep in mind that depending on the version of mlflow you use and the location of your runs (a local filesystem or a database) the tracking uri must be a valid uri (i.e. for old mlflow versions you cannot use "mlruns" relative path, but rather `file:///<absolute/path/to/mlruns` even if you are in the right folder). [According to mlflow documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#tracking-ui) using a relative path should work in most recent versions though, but I have never tried it.

**Long term solution**: The bug will be fixed in `kedro-mlflow==0.7.1` which will be released in the coming weeks. From this version on, you will be able to declare `port` and `host` directly in `mlflow.yml` as you are currently doing. It will be compatible only with `kedro>=0.17.1` though, so you will need to update your project template.